# MySQL - Match results against a list even if count is zero

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, union

I have a list of results that may only show up for a handful of states but I need to the full list of states to show each time.

Results come back like this:

```
AK 1
AL 5
CA 3
...
WV 4
WY 6
UN 10
```

BUT should come back as:

```
AK 1
AL 5
AR 0
AZ 0
CA 3
CO 0
CT 0
...
WV 4
WY 6
UN 10
```

Is it just a matter of an inner join against a list of states to ensure there is always the state for the count of zero? I have no table of states but I have a list of states like "AK","AL","AR" etc. I wasn't sure if it was possible to join like that. The query is far too large to post but if needed, I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Do you have a query you're already using?

Comment: Use subquery instead of joins ( use count inside subquery )

Comment: mysql optimizes joins better; one has to be careful using subqueries and know for certain how mysql will handle them.  But inner joins won't help here; use a LEFT JOIN like suggested in the answer below.

Comment: A join would be easy if I had a table of states but how about against a list like "AK","AL","AR" etc ?

Answer (score 2):

You could `LEFT JOIN` to a list of states, something like:

```
SELECT a.St
      ,COUNT(b.St) AS Ct
FROM State_List a
LEFT JOIN Other_Table b
  ON a.St = b.St
GROUP BY a.St
```

`LEFT JOIN` will return non-joining records from the table on the left side of the join, in this case a list of states. Then we `COUNT()` a field from the table that may or may not join.

Comment: If I was joining against a table, it would be fine but how about joining against a list like "AK","AL","AR" etc?

Comment: I believe you'll need to turn your list into a table.